# table cell element spanning across all cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position

I'm trying to displays sliders on a table. There are vertical and horizontal sliders. At this point, I am only concerned about their visualisation.

The goal is to show the slider when the mouse pointer hovers over the right or bottom side of the table. The problem I am trying to overcome is to have the sliders spanning across the entire row (horizontal sliders) or the entire column (vertical sliders) while the slider element itself is a child of the table cell `<td>`.

This example shows how the sliders *do not* span across (all shown at the same time in the screenshot).

[image]

```
<html>

<style>

table {
  position: relative;
}

.vslider {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
}

.vslider:hover {
    opacity: 1.0
}

.hslider {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
}

.hslider:hover {
    opacity: 1.0
}

td {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height : 40px;
  position: relative;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
}

</style>

<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        Alfreds Futterkiste
        <span class='vslider'></span>
        <span class='hslider'></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        Maria Anders
        <span class='vslider'></span>
        <span class='hslider'></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        Germany
        <span class='vslider'></span>
        <span class='hslider'></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        Centro comercial Moctezuma
        <span class='vslider'></span>
        <span class='hslider'></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        Francisco Chang
        <span class='vslider'></span>
        <span class='hslider'></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        Mexico
        <span class='vslider'></span>
        <span class='hslider'></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

I had some success disabling the `position: relative` for the horizontal sliders (red). If I disable the `td` position: relative, then the red sliders run all the way across.

[image]

However, at the same time, the vertical sliders are all positioned at the right-most side of the table which is not what I want.

Is there a way to make the `td { position: relative;}` only count for the vertical sliders and not for the red horizontal sliders (`.hslider`)?

Even if that's possible it leaves the problem of how the vertical sliders could span all across. Is there a solution for that as well or should I abandon the idea of using relative and absolute positioning entirely?

Comment: _"The goal is to show the slider when the mouse pointer hovers over the right or bottom side of the table."_ - but not even that is happening right now ...? You are only showing those "sliders" (not sure what that is actually supposed to mean, in this context - looks to me like you simply wanted to add some sort of _borders_ ...?) when these elements _themselves_ get hovered (which means I have to aim the mouse cursor _between_ two cells or two rows, but without touching the actual cells.)

Comment: That's right. With "sliders", I mean a border should appear between two columns (all the way across all rows) when the mouse hovers around the right-hand side of a cell, and conversely I would like to show a border between two rows when the mouse hovers at the bottom of a cell (again across all columns which is what I am struggling with). At the moment, the border is only shown for the particular cell in which the cell hovers.

Comment: I called it "slider" because the bar is meant to become an element to grab to slide/extend/shrink all columns or rows.

Comment: _"hovers around the right-hand side of a cell"_ - for stuff like that, you would have to place special "trigger" elements there, so that you can react to only part of the cell being hovered in the first place. But with anything nested in there, I don't see much other chance of affecting hover for anything else other than with `:has()`, which has no support by Firefox yet. And for columns instead of rows, likely to get even more complicated. I would look for a JavaScript solution ...